# How many edits can be made per day?

Tags: support, edits, rate-limiting

Once a user has editing privileges, how many edits can a user make per day on posts generally per site?

This [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) does not give information about the total limit per day